# Installing ZipArchive on PHP7.4?

Tags: php, zip, centos7, php-ziparchive

I'm running PHP7.4 on CentOS7 and am having trouble getting the zip module to show up when I run `php -m`

I tried installing php-zip and php-pecl-zip through yum, which gives me the following result:

```
Resolving Dependencies

--> Running transaction check

---> Package php72w-common.x86_64 0:7.2.34-1.w7 will be installed

Removing php72w-common.x86_64 0:7.2.34-1.w7 - u due to obsoletes from installed php-common-7.4.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64

--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.

--> Running transaction check

---> Package php72w-common.x86_64 0:7.2.34-1.w7 will be installed

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

Does this mean the zip module is already installed by default onto PHP7.4? Is there a reason I can't get it to activate?

I also added 40-zip.ini as per another Stackoverflow answer under `/etc/php.d/` but no dice. I've also restarted my apache webserver (`systemctl restart httpd`).

Can someone tell me what the message means and what I can do to install ZipArchive onto my server? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: PHP7 doesn't exist in the base Centos7 repos, so you've definitely added a 3rd-party repo for it. In order to not collide with base packages these repos use slightly different names, judging by the error message you'll probably want a package named `php72w-zip`.

Comment: Tried installing `php72w-zip` through `yum install php72w-zip`, but it looks like I'm getting the same "due to obsoletes" message as above.

I installed php (and other php modules) using the remi repo (http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm), if that helps provide some context.